# Help with book suggestions

Tags: support, resource-recommendation

If I am to ask for book suggestions on a certain topic, where should I ask? Should I ask on Physics Stack Exchange? If so, what tag should I use?

Comment: Hi Amanda Macaurenni -- I closed this as a duplicate of another question. Check out that linked question and it should answer everything you asked here. If something is unclear there and you need further help on how to ask, let us know!

Comment: Thanks for the generous support!

Comment: Just make sure you skim [the list of existing questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations?tab=Newest) to ensure what you're looking for hasn't been asked previously

Comment: Yeah of course!